# Unable to download 2 GB zip file from Angular in Safari browser

Tags: angular, safari, angular7

It has been hours now, since I am trying to figure out how to download large 2+ GB file using Angular in safari browser. I am using file-save to download the content. I am able to download the files in KB and MB in safari browser.

I am able to download the code in GB from chrome and IE.

I need to know how to download the data using safari browser.

I am getting "This web page is using significant memory" and it is redirecting to login page.

I am calling API from java to get the download content.

I am able to download thill 1.54 GB content and it is reloading the login page once again.

Can any one please help me on this.